# Getting data sent with Ajax from php?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

sorry if this has been asked many times but I can't get it to work.
I'm trying to build a restful website, I have a simple form:

```
<form action="/my/path" method="post" id="myformid">
Name <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Test">
</form>
```

I convert the data the user inputs using Javascript and I send them to my php file using Ajax:

```
function postData() {
    $('#myformid').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const json = JSON.stringify($("#myformid").serializeArray());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/my/path",
            data: json,
            success: function(){},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType : "application/json"
        });
    });
}
```

And I tried reading the data on php like:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$name = $data["name"];
```

The code works perfectly if I send a JSON in the request body using a tool like Postman, but from what I tested using Ajax the json data arrives as POST data, and I can read it using $_POST["name"], but non with the 'php://input' as I did.

How can I fix it so the JSON gets accepted even sent via Javascript?

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Look at `json` in the JavaScript or `$data` in the PHP. The clue is in the function name — `serializeArray` — it gives you an **array**, so it will have numerical indexes not properties like `name`.

Comment: Your missing the point. Use $_POST["name"] because that is the way HTML/Javascript 'talks' to the web server.

Comment: @jeff — Not with this code it isn't.

Comment: @Quentin json is ok, I also tried using the json I pasted into Postman. The problem is that if i use Ajax, I have to read from php using $_POST, while if I send it via postman in the message body the code works fine

Comment: @Ratacand — The JSON is OK? Really? So `[{"name":"name","value":"example"}]` is the JSON you want to send? And that is what you are sending with Postman?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try like this:

First I use an id attribute for each input i dont really like to serialize stuff but thats me you can do it your way here are the files.
your index.php:

```
 <form method="post" id="myformid">
  Name :<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <input type="submit"  value="Test">
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="myDiv">
  </div>
```

your javascript:

```
  //ajax function return a deferred object
    function _ajax(action,data){
      return $.ajax({
        url: 'request.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {action: action, data: data}
      })
    }
    //your form submit event
    $("#myformid").on('submit', function(event) {
      //prevent post
      event.preventDefault();
      //validate that name is not empty
      if ($("name").val() != "") {
        //parameters INS is insert data is the array of data yous end to the server
        var action = 'INS';
        var data = {
          name: $("#name").val()
        };
        console.log(data);
        //run the function and done handle the function
        _ajax(action,data)
        .done(function(response){
          console.log(response);
          //anppend name to the div
          $("#myDiv").append("<p>"+response.name+"</p>");
        });
      }
    });
```

your request.php file:

```
<?php
//includes and session  start here
//validate that request parameters are set
if (isset($_POST["action"]) && isset($_POST["data"])) {
  //getters
$action = $_POST["action"];
$data = $_POST["data"];
//switch to handle the action to perfom maybe you want to update with the form too ?
switch ($action) {
  case 'INS':
    // database insert  here..
    //return a json object
    echo json_encode(array("name"=>$data["name"]));
    break;
}
}
 ?>
```

Results:

[image]

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) of `.serializeArray()`.

> The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string.

And in the example given in the same page, it is clear that you will get an array in php,
to access an element, you should try-

```
`$data[0]['name']`
```

Also, have you tried print_r($data), is it NULL??

Answer (score -1):

Change your ajax codes

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/new.php",
        data: $("#myformid").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Also you need some changes in form

```
<form action="new.php" method="post" id="myformid">
Name <input type="text" name="name">
<input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Test">
```

And you can get POST data in php file like `$_POST['name']`

Answer (score -2):

You can set directly form serialize in ajax request to send params

```
function postData() {
    $('#myformid').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/my/path",
            data: $("#myformid").serialize(),
            success: function(){},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType : "application/json"
        });
    });
}
```

And you can get `POST` in your PHP using **$_POST**

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: `$("#myformid").serialize()` returns URL encoded data, not JSON. `$_POST` will not be populated because the `contentType` is JSON.

Comment: to send data to php why you need json data?

Comment: @Quentin and what is the benefits of sending JSON data in ajax request?

Comment: I don't really want to go into the details of why someone might want to send JSON (I wouldn't, at least for this example, when taken entirely out of context), but my points stand since (a) the question implies that sending JSON is the OPs goal and (b) Your code won't work because you claim to be sending JSON so PHP won't populate `$_POST`.